# Assigning value chosen from a UIPicker to a UITextField in Swift (also how to show and hide it)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, ios8

The title says it all. I am trying to assign a value (gender) that the user will select from a UIPicker and then the value will appear as the UITextField input using Swift.

Here is my code:

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var getGender: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()

@IBOutlet var genderTextField: UITextField! = nil

let gender = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.genderTextField.inputView = pickerView

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
    return 1
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return gender.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return gender[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    genderTextField.text = "\(gender[row])"

}
```

I am aware that this could be achieved if instead of a textfield I use a label and format it to look as a textfield. Then changing the value of the label.

I would also like to know how to show/hide the UIPicker when the label/textfield is clicked. Could anyone help me out with that?

Thank you so much for your advice!

Cheers.

---

Update:

I have done everything but the only thing that the compiler complains about is the line with the comment //ERROR. As I mentioned, it does not accept only this:

```
self.genderTextField.inputView = pickerView   //ERROR -> Requires more declarations! Read update section below!
```

It asks me to provide extra declarations such as:

```
pickerView!(pickerView: UIPickerView?, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int) 

pickerView!(pickerView: UIPickerView?, numberOfRowsInComponent: Int)
```

There are a couple other suggestions from Xcode but I do not know which one to use and how.

Help please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    textField.text = "\(gender[row])"
}
```

And to show/hide the picker (in viewDidLoad)

```
self.textField.inputView = pickerView
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have another question though. How do I assign the name textField to my UITextField so I can access the methods for the instance? I am guessing through an IBOutlet?

Comment: Programmatically or using interface builder?

Comment: I tried to implement the self.textfield.inputView = pickerView but there are many methods available such as:

pickerView!(pickerView: UIPickerView?, *)

And the asterisk can represent these:

*didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)

*numberOfRowsInComponent: Int)

etc.. etc..

Could you please help me out further?

Thank you for your response and time!

Comment: Yeah, you should use an IBOutlet.  Right after `class Settings: UIViewController {` add `@IBOutlet var textField : UITextField! = nil`  Then go into your .storyboard file, select the viewController the text field is in, control-click and drag from the yellow icon at the top of the viewController to the textfield, you should get a popup, click on textField.

Comment: I have everything in order. I used an IBOutlet for the text field and called it genderTextField so now I can access the methods for the UITextField. But now I do not know what to do next since I encounter what I mentioned in my last comment

Comment: You have to create an instance for the picker view using `@IBOutlet var pickerView : UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()`

Comment: Please read the UPDATE part of the post. I updated my code and have everything in order but I am missing the very last part of self.gendertextField.inputView = pickerView
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I see that.  Have you created an IBOutlet pickerView as I explained above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58558/discussion-between-trumpeter201-and-user3245995).

Answer (score -1):

Try this: self.txtSelectareRate.inputView = UIPickerView()